# After what episode was each Sword Art Offline episode expected to be viewed?

Tags: sword-art-online

Looking at the extras menu of Sword Art Online Bluray Set 1, I was reminded that there is a Sword Art Offline segment. Disk 1 has Episodes 1-4 of Sword Art Online and Sword Art Offline 1 and 2.

I am wondering, after what episode of Sword Art Online was each Sword Art Offline episode expected to be viewed? (not just Set 1 but all of Sword Art Online 1, Ex and 2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Japan, there were 9 BDs released for season 1, each of which had one episode of Sword Art Offline on it. Likewise, there were 9 BDs for season 2, and one episode of "Offline" on each. (Obviously, Extra Edition goes with its corresponding "Offline" episode.)

It makes sense that you would watch a given "Offline" episode after watching all the "Online" episodes that came on the same disc. Here are the correspondences:

### Season 1

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ BD ║ Episodes ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║  1 -  2  ║
║  2 ║  3 -  5  ║
║  3 ║  6 -  8  ║
║  4 ║  9 - 11  ║
║  5 ║ 12 - 14  ║
║  6 ║ 15 - 16  ║
║  7 ║ 17 - 19  ║
║  8 ║ 20 - 22  ║
║  9 ║ 23 - 25  ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```

### Season 2

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ BD ║ Episodes ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║  1 -  3  ║
║  2 ║  4 -  6  ║
║  3 ║  7 -  9  ║
║  4 ║ 10 - 12  ║
║  5 ║ 13 - 14  ║ (and also the recap episode)
║  6 ║ 15 - 17  ║
║  7 ║ 18 - 20  ║
║  8 ║ 21 - 22  ║
║  9 ║ 23 - 24  ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```