# Sword Art Online - is Offline season 2 included in the DVD?

Tags: sword-art-online

As seen in [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/30850/30322), there are 18 episodes of Sword Art Offline in total, 9 for each season.

In the DVD product shown [here on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DVD-Sword-Art-Online-Season-1-2-Extra-Edition-English-Dub-Offline-Jap-Dub/281967998939), the back of the DVD case says it includes seasons 1 and 2 (dub), along with Extra Edition 1-9 (dub) and Offline 1-9 (sub).

[image]

I'm wondering if episodes 1-9 of SAO Offline season 2 are included, since the case isn't clear on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suspect that the DVDs, like the Bluray I own, would normally come with them, however I suspect what you have there on eBay are bootlegs.

Quoting [Madman Entertainment](https://www.madman.com.au/actions/knowledgebase.do?method=browse&knowledgeBaseCategoryId=1):

> **How can I help stop DVD Piracy?**
>
> There has been a recent increase in these DVD sets being spotted and these are most certainly not real products but rather an illegal bootleg copy, usually imported from South East Asian countries and contain extremely bad subtitles and are of low quality. Easy signs to tell if they are real or not include:
>
> - Region 0 or All
> - **Very low disc count for entire series - eg. 26 episodes on 3 DVDs**
> - Anything with the company logos 'Anime Cartoon', 'AniDVD', AV, 'Manga Cartoon' and other companies with similar names usually linked to crime syndicates as well.
> - A web based email address printed on the DVD cover such as addresses ending with @yahoo.com or mail2000.com.tw etc
>
> Should you come across any of these products do not purchase them and if you feel this isn't right report it to the authorities or to piracy@madman.com.au, please include the store's name and if possible get details of the distributor, the closer we get to the source of the problem, the eaiser it is for us to stop the flow. The Pirate Anime FAQ site also has a lot more useful information regarding these illegal bootleg DVDs as well as other knock off anime merchandise and how you can avoid them. Alternatively you can also report it to the newly setup Anti-piracy task force. Remember the more reports that are reported the more likely something will be done about this problem. Piracy hurts the industry and you can help by spreading the word and reporting these illegitimate practices.

Now the eBay ad is saying that it has 49 episodes + EX + Offline on 3 disks. The [Sword Art Online DVD 1 On Rightstuf](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Sword-Art-Online-S-A-O-DVD-1-Aincrad-Part-1-Hyb) is 1 out of 4 for just season 1 and it says

> Sword Art Online 1 covers Aincrad Arc Part 1 and contains episodes 1-7

The [Bluray I own](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Sword-Art-Online-S-A-O-Blu-ray-Box-Set-1-Aincrad-Part-1-Hyb-LE) had 2 Bluray Disks and the 7 episodes were spread across both along with an episode or 2 of Sword Art Offline on each disk. There were 4 Bluray Collectors Editions Each Season and 1 for Sword Art Online EX (which was single disk) so in total there were about 17 disks (`(2 x (4 x 2)) + 1`). DVDs have a lower capacity than Blurays so they wouldn't use less disks.

Comparing this to what Madman has put on their website this leads me to believe that what you have is a bootleg.

Another problem with the cover is that it doesn't state which [DVD Region](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200492990) they are and if you're buying a legit DVD you need to know this so you can either get a DVD Player which plays that region, can be set to be a different region or set to Region 0 which ignores it (that's what my DVD/Bluray Player is set for DVDs. Bluray there is no Region 0).

Also while the eBay ad says

> With Malaysia Government issue Hologram

take this with a grain of salt. I got Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha on eBay which came with Season 1-3 and the 2 movies on 5 disks. It had a Hologram yet the episodes were clearly fan subs someone downloaded and burned onto a disk with whatever art they could find for menu backgrounds (since one used character cutouts but did a poor job removing the white around the character, blurring the edges to try and cover it up).

Comment: So basically any of the ones on eBay claiming to have seasons 1+2 + Extra Edition + Offline all together for only $20-30 are the fake ones. They're all from Malaysia, too. In that case, I'm really glad I didn't jump at the offer. Thanks for your quick answer. :)

Comment: @mbomb007 yeh i would suspect they are all bootlegs. you're probably best to buy from Right Stuff unless there's a problem like they don't ship to your country but i don't see any exclusion list on their [policies page](http://www.rightstufanime.com/policies) which talks about international shipping from the US

Comment: Wow. On DVD, the standard editions total at $340, including Extra Edition. Blu-ray is 1.5 times that.

Comment: @mbomb007 sounds right. the other option is to stream on [crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/sword-art-online). the subscription cost per month is much cheaper but it's all online and thus you need net access to watch them and it appears Crunchyroll only has EX and 2 but [Aniplex's own site](http://aniplexchannel.com/show-page/sword-art-online/page/2) has Season 1

Comment: we have a list of [legal streaming sources](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587) which you can check out if getting the DVDs is too much but i prefer the DVDs/Bluray

Comment: I'll consider buying them, because SAO is my favorite anime so far, and it's likely to stay my favorite. I'll have to look more into those streaming sources though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52047/discussion-between-mbomb007-and-memor-x).